# Can a finite class in a model of ZFC contain a set that is not definable?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

**Terminology**:

Let $\mathfrak{A} = (A,\in^\mathfrak{A})$ be a model of **ZFC** (for simplicity let it be an "inner model", i.e. it is itself an element in the universe $\mathfrak{U}$).

A unary predicate over $A$ I call a "class", i.e. the classes are the subsets $K \subseteq A$ s.t. $K = [\![\varphi(x)]\!]^\mathfrak{A}$ for some first-order expression $\varphi \in L^{\{\in\}}$ having no free variables other than $x$, where $[\![\varphi(x)]\!]^\mathfrak{A} := \{a \in A \mid \mathfrak{A} \models \varphi[a]\}$.

A finite class is just a class $K$ that is finite. For simplicity, we can forget about the general case of a finite cardinal and restrict ourselves to the case of $|K|$ being a "counting number" **n** $\geq$ **2**, maybe even just the case $|K| =$ **2**, as the answer to that should be enough for the general case I believe.

A set $a \in A$ s.t. $\{a\}$ is a class I call a "definable set", i.e. it is a set that can be "pinned down" using some first order expression.

Comment: On terminology: "[inner model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model)" has a technical meaning in set theory which is different from what you wrote. In fact, an inner model of $\mathfrak{U}$ is never an element of $\mathfrak{U}$, since it contains all the ordinals of $\mathfrak{U}$. Your $\mathfrak{A}$ is just an ordinary model in $\mathfrak{U}$.

Comment: Also: Your distinction between "finite cardinal" and "counting number" is not clear. The finite cardinals are exactly the natural numbers. Perhaps what you intended is to distinguish the finite cardinals in $\mathfrak{A}$ from the finite cardinals in $\mathfrak{U}$. Note that $\mathfrak{A}$ might contain finite cardinals that are non-standard from the point of view of $\mathfrak{U}$, but that the finite cardinals of $\mathfrak{U}$ correspond to an initial segment of the finite cardinals of $\mathfrak{A}$.